# Can't Unmute YouTube Videos with Revolution Slider on Mobile

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, revolution-slider

I'm using Revolution Slider in WordPress and I'm running into an issue where on mobile devices, I cannot unmute YouTube videos. I have videos in the slider to be muted on load in and to autoplay. I have interaction and controls both allowed. However, when I try to click the unmute button on the screen, it simply pauses/plays the video. I'm not sure if the pause/play button that appears somehow overlaps and the YT controls are underneath or something.  It actually doesn't look like the controls generated from YouTube but instead the RS native controls.  I tried turning controls and interaction both off but unsurprisingly, this causes absolutely zero action to happen when you click/press on the video, not even pause/play it.

[image]

You can view the issue in action at http://www.hagentertainment.com. The slide in issue is slide #2 out of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Being an issue related to mobile and iframes makes it relatively difficult to diagnose with 100% efficacy. I used Browerstack to open a connection on a Galaxy S20 and noticed the issue as you described.

Using the Dev Tools, I was able to get it to allow the mute button to be clicked by changing the `&enablejsapi=1` to `&enablejsapi=0`. You can see in this screenshot below that after doing that, it allowed it to be clicked. You also have a JavaScript parse error showing in the console - that could potentially be preventing a JS API controller (built into Revolution Slider?) from functioning correctly.

So it looks like your options (for the moment) are to fix that JS error and see if it works, or disable the JS API in the url of the videos

[image: Image with the mute button]

Comment: I followed the steps to remove the errors that the console was reporting but unfortunately, that did not help.